# Samsung SmartThings on LineageOS getting "Galaxy SmartTag is only supported on Galaxy devices running Android 8.0 or higher"

Tags: samsung, lineageos, android-10

I'm trying to add a Samsung Galaxy SmartTag to my install of Samsung SmartThings on LinageOS 10 but I'm getting

[image: Samsung SmartThings error]

> **Can't add this device** *"Galaxy SmartTag is only supported on Galaxy devices running Android 8.0 or higher"*

Is there a way to add SmartTags to a LinageOS install of SmartThings? Is there a way to mock the operating system or otherwise work around this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Samsung devices are heavily modified by Samsung. LineageOS and "Samsung Android" are different at a large number of points regarding the installed system components and provided APIs. As all those modified system components are closed-source it is not possible to adapt them to LineageOS (if some one would really would try it as this would be a very complex task).

Therefore the only way to get such apps running with an reasonable effort is using a ROM that bases on an original Samsung ROM (or just use the original ROM of your device).

But there is one exception: if the Samsung Galaxy SmartTag app requires Knox, the security feature of Samsung Galaxy devices, then you are totally out of luck, because Knox permanently disables itself once you have unlocked the bootloader.

Comment: "with an reasonable effort", I don't consider recompiling LOS, or using Magisk unreasonable and it seems somewhat likely that something like that could get what I want.

Comment: @EvanCarroll So you want to compare existing libraries with those from Samsung devices, compare the available methods, reimplement them on LOS, and also reverse engineer the different libraries required for implementing the additional features used by Samsung specific apps and then find a way to integrate them in LOS? Remember that Samsung not just adds a few libraries but makes modification throughout the whole system. Which one is relevant for you without having the code is a really tough job.

Comment: No, I want whatever mechanism that triggers that warning in the Samsung App to be bypassed. It's very likely just an API call for a device ID or make/model. There are already tools to spoof those things (because Samsung wouldn't be the first app provider to do this).